# Rewrite rules in my htaccess is possible causing authentication log in to pop up three times consecutively

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, mediawiki

The authentication log-in pops up three times when I try to access the protected subdirectory in my server. I think the rewrite rules is setting off the authentication multiple times. Obviously, I only need to check once if the user knows the credentials.
Also, any feedback in the code is welcomed. This is my first time using htaccess.
Thank you in advance.

here is the www/.htaccess file:

```
#MediaWiki Rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)$ mediawiki/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki/*$ mediawiki/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki$ mediawiki/index.php [L,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 hours"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

here is the www/mediawiki/.htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home2/lafhousi/www/mediawiki/.htpasswd
require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 "Authorization Required"
```

Comment: Your HTTPS redirect should be the first thing you do here, not come after other, internal rewrites. Plus, you should not manipulate stuff _inside_ the BEGIN/END WORDPRESS comments - WP will _overwrite_ that section, when you flish your permalink settings.

Comment: The HTTP and HTTPS version are treated as two different sites by the browser - so if you switch between them, it will ask for the password again initially. If you wanted to avoid that users starting on HTTP will be asked twice, you will need to _not_ ask for a password, when the HTTP version of your site is requested. You will need an ALLOW directive to check whether %{HTTPS} is off, and SATISFY to allow that as an alternative to a valid user for granting access.

Comment: Thank you for you responses. I'm a bit dense; how would that look like? I tried to put
`
allow %{https} == on
satisfy any
`
after the require valid-user line, it didn't work, i didn't think allow could be used for checking if https is off.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use `%{}` syntax directly with that directive, you might need to use SetEnvIf or similar first, to define you own variable. https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/apache-authorization/ has some examples. `Require expr %{…}` might be another way to do this, if you’re on an Apache 2.4, needs to be grouped into a RequireAny directive then together with the one that requires a valid user.